# Linux equivalent of Windows' sndrec32?

Tags: linux, open-source, audio, audio-recording

I'm looking for a small (in all ways you can think of), no-frills, GUI app for Linux which records audio, plays back the recording, and can save it to a file. Not something large and full-featured like, say, Audacity. The user interface must be simple and familiar; nothing zany looking. In other words, I want this:

[image]

on Linux. Must be libre and gratis.

The closest thing I've found so far is the [GNOME Sound Recorder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundRecorder):

[image]

but its interface is too hip and modern for my taste.

Comment: VLC can do this.  I think Audacity can grab live from a mic.

Comment: Have you tried KWave? http://kwave.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: @acejavelin: No, I haven't. If it meets my requirement, make it an answer. Although this was months ago, I don't quite need it right now...